# Tableau Map view Continent List

Tags: tableau-api

I have been trying to clean my data and have a column represent the various continents and ultimately have them represented on map view.

But it doesn't consider that column to be Geography and even when i forcefully make it, the same still does not show up in map view. Any suggestions?

Africa
Asia
Europe
North America
Oceania   (Tried without this too)
South America

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have continent as geographic role in Tableau.
What you could do however is look for a list which maps countries to continents and then join with your original data source on continent.
This way all your data values get replicated for each country. When you then select the country column as geographic region you can get the effect you want.

List could be something like [this](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/country_continent).

Comment: Thanks. I shall give this a go